# Most efficient way of executing/validating values in javascript by getting mysql values using AJAX OR Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to select the entire table from mysql and validate those values using javascript. I know I can do this using AJAX which will send a HTTP request to the server but I feel sending too many HTTP request to the server can be quite bad as the page will load much slower, or I could store the value as the page load in the client cookie. I think it will be much faster but might be too much data stored in the cookie specially if the mysql table is too big.

What do you guys think should be the best approach for this? Is it a good thing to store mysql data in a client cookies

UPDATE

Say I have 100 Items in mysql, these 100 items I needed them displayed in a page dynamically, as the next time the page is loaded there might be 101. That means I need to validate how many items are there and allocate them to the page, and im not sure how to do that and where either client side or server side.

Comment: Why not validate information using the server? The client really shouldn't handle large computational jobs like that.

Comment: Yoda is spot on with this one.  Any browser validation should be about user convenience and should be repeated on the server anyway.

If you have a large data set to validate against, it's better to send the smaller set of values to the server and retrieve the response.

Comment: I updated the question with abit more information

Comment: So you're displaying the data from the table, and you want to check if new entries have been added since the page was displayed?

Comment: It works kinda like stackoverflow, There are now 4 replies here. there cant be 4<div> to allocate each replies. similar thing I want to do with my page. I dont want to have 100 div to allocate 100 items from mysql as there could be 101 next time the page is loaded.

Comment: you want to be using a loop to create 1 div for each row in the database, i think. The loop will iterate the same number of times are there are rows in your result set. This is how most code deals with an unpredictable amount of repeating data. You can google how to fetch data from mysql and loop through the rows until the end. Within the loop, build a string of HTML to output to the page, which contains the div and the relevant database data from the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an AJAX call for the information, do the validating of what data you need/don't need, then send it back as an array. When you get the array back you can do a for loop through the array creating the div's for each index/object in the array. This way if you have 5 items that need to be shown, you can show them. Then later if you have 7, you can show them as well. Hope this helps!